# Apache Spark working with pipe delimited CSV files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new to Apache Spark and am trying to use SchemaRDD with my pipe delimited text file.  I have a standalone installation of Spark 1.5.2 on my Mac using Scala 10. I have a CSV file with the following representative data and I am trying to split the following into 4 different files based on the first value (column) of the record.  I would very much appreciate any help I can get with this.

```
1|1.8|20140801T081137|115810740
2|20140714T060000|335|22159892|3657|0.00|||181
2|20140714T061500|335|22159892|3657|0.00|||157
2|20140714T063000|335|22159892|3657|0.00|||156
2|20140714T064500|335|22159892|3657|0.00|||66
2|20140714T070000|335|22159892|3657|0.01|||633
2|20140714T071500|335|22159892|3657|0.01|||1087
3|34|Starz
3|35|VH1
3|36|CSPAN: Cable Satellite Public Affairs Network
3|37|Encore
3|278|CMT: Country Music Television
3|281|Telehit
4|625363|1852400|Matlock|9212|The Divorce
4|625719|1852400|Matlock|16|The Rat Pack
4|625849|1846952|Smallville|43|Calling
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you include your own attempts you'll have a much better chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 14):

Note: Your csv file does not have the same number of fields in each row - this cannot be parsed as is into a DataFrame. (SchemaRDD has been renamed to DataFrame.) Here is something you can do if your csv file were well-formed:

launch spark-shell or spark-submit with --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0  in order to parse csv files easily ([see here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)). In Scala, your code would be, assuming your csv file has a header - if yes, it is easier to refer to columns:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", '|').load("/path/to/file.csv")
// assume 1st column has name col1
val df1 = df.filter( df("col1") === 1)  // 1st DataFrame
val df2 = df.filter( df("col1") === 2)  // 2nd DataFrame  etc...
```

Since your file is not well formed, you would have to parse each of the different lines differently, so for example, do the following:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("/path/to/file.csv")

case class RowRecord1( col1:Int, col2:Double, col3:String, col4:Int)
def parseRowRecord1( arr:Array[String]) = RowRecord1( arr(0).toInt, arr(1).toDouble, arr(2), arr(3).toInt)

case class RowRecord2( col1:Int, col2:String, col3:Int, col4:Int, col5:Int, col6:Double, col7:Int)
def parseRowRecord2( arr:Array[String]) = RowRecord2( arr(0).toInt, arr(1), arr(2).toInt, arr(3).toInt, arr(4).toInt, arr(5).toDouble, arr(8).toInt)

val df1 = lines.filter(_.startsWith("1")).map( _.split('|')).map( arr => parseRowRecord1( arr )).toDF
val df2 = lines.filter(_.startsWith("2")).map( _.split('|')).map( arr => parseRowRecord2( arr )).toDF
```

Comment: Hi KrisP,  Thank you so much for your help.  I tried your first few lines of code and it worked great!  I am going to try the rest of your example and then split the files (which has different num columns) into multiple files with the same number of columns based on the value of COL0...

Comment: Hi KrisP, would you also know how to save the output to pipe delimited files?  I think the output of the df2.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/Users/temp/parsed1.txt")  command is comma delimited by default and breaks things up into multiple files.  If possible, I am also trying to write the results directly into Amazon Redshift to make the workflow more streamlined.  Thanks very much for all of your help.

Comment: This works for me only if I use double quotes for the delimiter:
.option("delimiter","|")
Otherwise I get the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Delimiter cannot be more than one character

Answer (score 7):

In PySpark, the command is:

```
df = spark.read.csv("filepath", sep="|")
```