# Unable to read raw file view in dataframe as structured view

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am reading a .csv file into Databricks, but when I read the file I display the result as what is shown in the .csv file - along with the pipe characters, with everything being displayed in one column. This allows me to work on the data. However, I am now trying to take this raw view and read the data as a structured table.

The data that I am displaying in the raw format, in my dataframe is as follows:

```
|Name|Surname|Age|Gender|

|John|Doe|32|M

|Lisa|Doe|53|F
```

I would like to take the above and have my output as follows:

```
|Name|Surname|Age|Gender|
|----|-------|---|------|
|John|Doe|32|M
|Lisa|Doe|53|F
```

The following is what I do to get the initial output in my dataframe:

```
df = rdd_df.toDF()
df = df.withColumn('Line', df['_1'].getItem("_c0"))
df.show()
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246499/apache-spark-working-with-pipe-delimited-csv-files) help? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53597742/14165730)

Comment: Hi @mck I followed the link provided. Unfortunately, it does not answer my question.

Comment: could you show what you have tried and include that in your question?

Comment: Hi @mck I have edited the question to include the first step taken to get the view I initially get.

Comment: Did you try `df = spark.read.csv("filepath", sep="|")`?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I am able to read the file. However, the code provided in the question shows how I get to my result of displaying the results as a raw view. I would like to take that view and convert it back to the structured table view

Comment: try `spark.read.csv(rdd_df, sep='|')`

Comment: @mck I tried that now but unfortunately for the following error: TypeError("path can be only string, list or RDD")

Comment: isn't `rdd_df` an RDD?

Comment: @mck It is. But that is before the other code. Would it not exclude the transformations I am doing after?

Comment: @mck your script worked. I just read my other dataframes as rdd -- I am still new to stackoverflow. How do I mark your answer as the solution?